# How to get scanner input to not trigger third method?

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment and I mostly have it finished but I am having an issue with the last method. I'm trying to write a `continueGame()` method that will ask the user if they want to continue to play, and accept "y" or "n". If answered "y", the program starts again. If answered "n", the program stops and a message is shown. The problem is I need it to trigger the `continueGame()` method only when `userChoice == answer`. This is a number guessing game with an object oriented approach.

I've tried to call the `continueGame()` method inside my `else if(userChoice == answer)` statement but it doesn't seem to work. Even when my other `if/else if` statements are triggered, it continues to the `continueGame()` method.

Here is the main driver for the game

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGame
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      GameOptions opt = new GameOptions(); // Your created class
      int userChoice = -1234;
      int answer = -1234;
      boolean keepPlaying = true;

      System.out.println("Guess the Number Game\n");

      while (keepPlaying == true) {
         answer = (int) (Math.random() * 10)+1;

         //Create a getChoice method in your class and make sure it accepts a Scanner argument 
         userChoice = opt.getChoice(input);

         //Create a checkAnswer method in your class. Make sure it accepts two integer arguments and a Scanner argument
         opt.checkAnswer(userChoice, answer, input);

         // Create a continueGame method in  your class and make sure it accepts a Scanner argument
         keepPlaying = opt.continueGame(input);    
      } 
      System.out.println("Thanks for playing.");
   }
}
```

Here is the class that I am working on for the methods. Note that I can not make any modifications to the main driver file.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;

public class GameOptions {
    int count = 0;
    boolean cont = true;
    //getChoice Method for NumberGame
    public int getChoice(Scanner scnr) {

        System.out.println("Please choose a number between 1 and 10: ");
        int userGuess = 0;
        String input = scnr.next();
        try {
            userGuess = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > 10) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value. Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
            }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Error - Enter Numerical Values Only");
            return userGuess;
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    public void checkAnswer(int userChoice, int answer, Scanner scnr) {
        if (userChoice > answer && userChoice < 11) {
            System.out.println("Too high. Try again.");
            count++;
        } else if (userChoice < answer && userChoice > 0) {
            System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");
            count++;
        } else if (userChoice == answer) {
            System.out.println("You got it! Number of tries: " + count);
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
        }
    }

    public static boolean continueGame(Scanner scnr) {

        String input = scnr.nextLine();
        if (input.toLowerCase().equals("y")){
            return true;
        } else if (input.toLowerCase().equals("n")){
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter either y or n: ");
            return continueGame(scnr);
        }
    }
}
```

So I should be able to enter a number, and if its lower than the answer it will tell me I am too low, if its higher than the answer it will tell me that its too high, if its equal it will tell me I won and prompt me to press "y" or "n" if I want to continue. Another issue I am running into is that I am getting "Would you like to play again? (y/n)" no matter whether I guess the right number or not and my only option is to hit "y" or "n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the driver is written (I guess) is coming from your instructor/lecturer/professor, right?

With the driver (as it is), you don't need to call continueGame method from checkAnswer method. The driver is going to call it.

Just run the driver and it will work. If you have a proper IDE (eclipse or Netbeans), trace through and see what the input accepted is (I think there is line-feed in the accepted answer).

Try this (I just changed the loop structure; yours is also valid):

```
public static boolean continueGame(Scanner scnr) { 
while (true) {
    String input = scnr.nextLine().trim(); // to remove white spaces and line-feed
    if (input.toLowerCase().equals("y")){
        return true;
    } else if (input.toLowerCase().equals("n")){
        return false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter either y or n: ");
    }
}
}
```

Added for checkAnswer method to keep the user guess the answer until he gets correct:

```java
public static checkAnswer(/*three arguments*/) {
    boolean correct = false;
    while (! correct) {
        // accept input
        if (answer.equals(input)) {
            correct = true;
            // print required correct/congrats messages here
        } else {
            // print required input/try again messages here
        }
    }
    // print would you like to play again with new answer y/n message here.
}
```

In my opinion, printing "play again with new answer y/n message" should go into continueGame method (from last portion of checkAnswer) method to stick to encapsulation concepts.

Comment: Is that loop supposed to be added within the checkAnswer method? Or is outside of the method? Just a bit confused as I tried putting that inside the checkAnswer method but it won't work because it doesn't return any values.

Comment: No, the driver is calling checkAnswer ... then continueGame methods. Put the loop in continueGame method. I have edited the answer.

Comment: My bad I just realized what you said. It does work but it only gives me one attempt to guess the number. I need it to loop back to the initial questions of "Please choose a number between 1 and 10: " after I get the wrong number. What its doing now is that it will ask me to enter a number, if I get a number too low it will display "Too low. Try Again" but it won't prompt me to enter another number, if I enter another number it will give me "Invalid entry. Please enter either y or n." so its skipping straight to the continueGame() method

Comment: My bad. Yes, you need a loop in checkAnswer method. I will change my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Hey Edward, I seem to be getting really close, the code you posted fixed some of my problems but now if I enter a number that is higher than the answer it seems to be stuck on that userChoice value. No matter how low of a number I input I still get a message of "Too high. Try Again." I'm assuming this is because the value isn't actually changing?

Comment: May I see your current code? You may edit your question and add additional boxes.

Comment: sorry to follow up so late. So I ended up figuring out what was wrong with my problem, I used some of the logic you provided with the checkAnswer and continueGame methods and went back and started from the top. It turned out most of my methods were not working well together and I had to rewrite my getChoice method. Thank you for helping me on this I really appreciate it. I could post the updated code if anyone would like to see how I went about fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

The driver class is calling `continueGame()` inside the while loop. If you're not allowed to modify that class then presumably asking at every iteration is the intended behaviour.

You should move `System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");` into the `continueGame()` method so that it only asks when that method is called.

Comment: Hmm I could try that. The only thing is that the way the program is intended to work is that it should only ask you if you want to play again once userChoice == answer. Here is an example of a run through of what the program SHOULD look like if coded correctly.

Guess the Number Game

Please choose a number between 1 and 10: 10
Too high. Try again.
Please choose a number between 1 and 10: 5
Too low. Try again.
Please choose a number between 1 and 10: 8
You got it! Number of tries: 3
Would you like to play again? (Y/N): k
Invalid entry. Please enter Y or N: y

Comment: The only way to do that would be to add a boolean to your `GameOptions` class that is set to `true` when they get the answer. Then in your `continueGame()` method check if that boolean is true - if it is display the keep playing spiel, and if it isn't then just return true.

Comment: @Matt ... your comment suggests to introduce state into a meant-to-be-stateless class.

Comment: @EdwardAung It doesn’t say anywhere in the question that the GameOptions class is meant to be stateless. In fact by definition it does have a state, because it is tracking count. Where have you got that idea from?

Comment: @Matt count is used solely inside the function (to loop). I could educated-guess the intent of this assignment because I helped design 3000-level Software Engineering course materials in a university.